# Get english letters if locale=en and nordic characters if it's not

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to get english characters only (26 chars) if I select english language, and all 29 nordic characters if I select any of the nordic languages. I struggle to find out how to get this to work.

```
public LetterAdapter(Context c) {
    letters=new String[29];
    for (int a = 0; a < 26; a++) {
        letters[a] = "" + (char)(a+'A');
    }
    letters[26] = "\u00C6";
    letters[27] = "\u00D8";
    letters[28] = "\u00C5";

    letterInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
```

letters[26],[27],[28] are the special characters that is added in the nordic alphabet and which I try to show/hide if the locale is set to either "en" or the others. I've tried using this:

```
    public int getCount() {
    if(!Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en){
        return letters.length;
    }else{
        return letters.length-3;
    }
}
```

This does nothing, I either get all 29 chars, or only 26.

this is my getView

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button letterBtn;
    if (convertView == null) {
        letterBtn = (Button)letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, parent, false);
    } else {
        letterBtn = (Button) convertView;
    }
    letterBtn.setText(letters[position]);
    return letterBtn;
}
```

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Java to get the national alphabet.

The English alphabet is easy, because the letters A-Z are consecutive in the ASCII character set, which is also used by Unicode. In other character sets, e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout), that is not the case.

You have to provide the various alphabets you need to support.

---

For the SO users out there, that don't know what we are talking about, some languages have extra letters in the alphabet. For comparison:

```
English:   a bcdefghijklmno pqrs tu vwxyz
Danish:    a bcdefghijklmno pqrs tu vwxyzæøå
Norwegian: a bcdefghijklmno pqrs tu vwxyzæøå
Swedish:   a bcdefghijklmno pqrs tu vwxyzåäö
German:    aäbcdefghijklmnoöpqrsßtuüvwxyz
```

This affects dictionary sort order, where German may sort like shown, but can be [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Sorting).

In Java, a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) can be used to sort strings appropriately for different languages (locales), but it can't be used to retrieve the alphabet.

---

**Update**

The code in the `LetterAdapter` should create the array with the appropriate length, and should be able to support alphabets like the German shown above. In addition, the javadoc of [getLanguage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29) states that `getLanguage().equals("xx")` is bad.

So, potential implementation, replacing letter array with letter string:

```
private final String letters;
public LetterAdapter(Context c) {
    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if (lang.equals(new Locale("da").getLanguage())
        this.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\u00C6\u00D8\u00C5"; // Danish
    else if (lang.equals(new Locale("no").getLanguage())
        this.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\u00C6\u00D8\u00C5"; // Norwegian
    else if (lang.equals(new Locale("sv").getLanguage())
        this.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\u00C5\u00C4\u00D6"; // Swedish
    else if (lang.equals(new Locale("de").getLanguage())
        this.letters = "A\u00C4BCDEFGHIJKLMNO\u00D6PQRS\u00DFTU\u00DCVWXYZ"; // German
    else
        this.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // English (and others)

    letterInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
public int getCount() {
    return this.letters.length();
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button letterBtn;
    if (convertView == null) {
        letterBtn = (Button)letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, parent, false);
    } else {
        letterBtn = (Button) convertView;
    }
    letterBtn.setText(String.valueOf(this.letters.charAt(position)));
    return letterBtn;
}
```

Comment: So how am I going to implement what I want? Basically what I'm trying to do is show letters[] value 0-25 (english alphabet) when the locale is in english, and the entire array if it's not english. I am able to show either the entire array by doing letters.length; in getCount(), or english alphabet by doing letters.length-3;. But I am not able to alternate the two depending on language selected.

Comment: What "entire array"? Danish, Swedish and German are 3 different alphabets. Other languages add letters with diacritical marks. To support all, you'd have to show all unicode letters. That's a *huge* list.

Comment: If you check my code, letterAdapter to be specific, I parse through the array to get the characters from A-Z and then manually input ÆØÅ to fill the array. What I want to do is display A-Z when Locale is set to english, and display A-Å if danish. So if language=danish I want the entire array, A-Å, get displayed in the gridView(which makes buttons for each char), and A-Z if language=english.

Don't really know how to explain it otherwise.

Comment: Added implementation of what I mean. There is no *single/entire* array. Each language is a different array, with a different length. Anyway, I replaced the array of strings with an "array of characters", also called a string.

Comment: I just read through the javadoc and I see what you mean now. I tried your implementation, and I still have the same issue. with your implementation it only shows the english alphabet.

Comment: What is the default locale for the JVM? Debug the code and check the value of `lang`.

Comment: the default language is english. I put 3 Log.d, infront the first if(lang.equals), right after it and after the else. It prints english before and after, even if I changed the locale.

Comment: So if your locale is English, why would you be expecting a Danish alphabet? From code that uses the locale to choose an alphabet?